# Unable to parse JSON from the HTTP response

Tags: json, swift

Why am I unable to parse JSON from the HTTP response via the following code?

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {
                (data, response, error) in
                var jsonError: NSError?
                let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as [String: AnyObject]
                if jsonError != nil {
                    return
                }

                // ...
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

**Output**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late.... but I think you are trying to parse the error as well so add an else part and and the dictionary to be serialized will only be parsed if there is the data ... your code can be modified as follows

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if (jsonError != nil) {
                return
            } else {
               var jsonError: NSError?
               let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as [String: AnyObject]}

            // ...
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```